# neo4j logger not going to file

Tags: java, logging, neo4j

Have a Transaction Event Handler to do logging for changes made via the Embedded API.

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.event.TransactionData;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.event.TransactionEventHandler;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.StringLogger;
import org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;


public class WarehouseTransactionEventHandler  implements TransactionEventHandler<String> {
private static Logger log = Logger
        .getLogger(WarehouseTransactionEventHandler.class);



  public void afterCommit(TransactionData data, String state) {

      Iterable<Node> createdNodes = data.createdNodes();
      for(Node n: createdNodes) {
        log.info("AfterCommit ########: created node:" + n.getId());
        log.log(Level.ALL,"AfterCommit ########: created node:" + n.getId());
      }



  }


  public void afterRollback(TransactionData data, String state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  public String beforeCommit(TransactionData data) throws Exception {
      Iterable<Node> createdNodes = data.createdNodes();
      for(Node n: createdNodes) {
          log.info("BeforeCommit ######: created node:" + n.getId());
          log.log(Level.ALL,"BeforeCommit ######: created node:" + n.getId());
      }

      return null;
  }


}
```

Then I register it in my code that does the writing

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH)
graphDb.registerTransactionEventHandler(new WarehouseTransactionEventHandler())
// do stuff
graphDb.shutdown();
```

So when I run my code it seems to be working

```
INFO: AfterCommit ########: created node:14
Jun 26, 2013 12:24:22 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: AfterCommit ########: created node:15
Jun 26, 2013 12:24:22 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: AfterCommit ########: created node:17
Jun 26, 2013 12:24:22 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: AfterCommit ########: created node:16
Jun 26, 2013 12:24:22 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: AfterCommit ########: created node:19
Jun 26, 2013 12:24:22 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: AfterCommit ########: created node:18
Jun 26, 2013 12:24:22 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: AfterCommit ########: created node:21
Jun 26, 2013 12:24:22 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: AfterCommit ########: created node:20
Jun 26, 2013 12:24:22 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: AfterCommit ########: created node:22
```

However I have gone through the logs and can't find any of these AfterCommit messages.  My log.properties hasn't been changed except for setting `java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=10000000`

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `log4j`, it works fine with me.

Initializing the `logger` @ the beginning of your app, it will log your messages wherever you want it to be.. like this:

```
static {
    try {
        String logFileName = "neo4j.log";
        RollingFileAppender fa = new RollingFileAppender();
        fa.setName("NEO4JLOGGER");
        fa.setFile(logFileName);
        fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout(
                "[%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}]  %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"));
        fa.setAppend(true);
        fa.activateOptions();
        Logger.getLogger("CLASSES NEEDED TO BE LOGGED").setLevel(Level.ALL);
        Logger.getLogger("CLASSES NEEDED TO BE LOGGED").addAppender(fa);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Intialize Logger :: Failed...  \n   ", ex);
    }
}
```